# Java Error: The operator is undefined for the arguement. Why?

Tags: java

In my code below you will notice that on lines 30 and 37 these two lines of code

```
    fahrenheit = (9.0/5)*(cel+32);

    celsius = (5.0/9)*(fahren-32);.
```

These pieces of code are giving me the error `"the operator - (or) + is undefined for the argument type(s) double[], int"` I am just learning Java and this question is for a problem that I have to do for school. I had to have two methods (the ones that are listed) and have to make a table with the arrays that have been built. But I can't go any farther because I keep getting that above error. Am I doing something wrong with my methods? Am I passing the array to the methods wrong? I didn't know if the way I wrote the methods was correct. So I am also hoping that somebody can tell me the correct way to do that as well.

```
public class CelciusFahrenheit {
public static void main(String [] args){
    // creates array cel and fills it. 
    double[] cel = {
            40, 39, 38, 
            37, 36, 35, 
            34, 33, 32, 31
    };


    // creates array fahren
    double[] fahren = new double[90];

    // fills array fahren
    for (int i = 30; i < fahren.length; i++)
        fahren[i] = i + 1;

    // passes fahren to method
    FahrenheitToCelsius(fahren);

    // passes cel to method
    CelsiusToFahrenheit(cel);

    }

// Method CelsiusToFahrenheit start
public static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(double[] cel){
    double fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = (9.0/5)*(cel+32);
    return fahrenheit;
    // Method CelsiusToFahrenheit end
}
// Method FahrenheitToCelsius start
public static double FahrenheitToCelsius(double[] fahren){
    double celsius;
    celsius = (5.0/9)*(fahren-32);
    return celsius;
    // Method FahrenheitToCelsius end
}
```

}

Comment: `+` is not defined on arrays. `cel` and `fahren` are both of the type `double[]`, hence you can't add an `int` to either one of them.

Comment: cel is an array, which you cannot multiply by.

Comment: Are you trying to add that int to every element in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fahrenheit` is an *array* of `double`, not a `double`. You can't subtract a number from it. Same problem with `cel`: it's an array of `double`, and you can't add a number to it. Perhaps you meant to add or subtract an *element* inside the array? not the array itself. Or more likely: you want to pass a `double` as parameter, not a `double[]`.

Let's go one step at a time. First, fix these methods:

```
public static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(double cel) {
    double fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = (9.0/5)*(cel+32);
    return fahrenheit;
}

public static double FahrenheitToCelsius(double fahren) {
    double celsius;
    celsius = (5.0/9)*(fahren-32);
    return celsius;
}
```

Now you can call them over each of the elements in the input array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fahren.length; i++)
    System.out.print(FahrenheitToCelsius(fahren[i]) + " ");

System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < cel.length; i++)
    System.out.print(CelsiusToFahrenheit(cel[i]) + " ");
```

Comment: So I don't quite understand a few things. So bare with me. ( I might just be babbling nonesense) I want to pass the arrays into the methods, and have each element go through the method process. I think that is what you are saying. But when I remove the [] from (double[] fahren) etc, the lines where I pass the arrays into the method get errors. "They say The method CelsiusToFahrenheit(double) in the type CelciusFahrenheit is not applicable for the arguments (double[])" Then also where would I put the for loops that you mention? Thanks again for you help and for baring with me.

Comment: If you want you can pass the whole array to the method, but then you'll have to move the loops inside the method. Or you can do as I suggest, and pass a single `double` to the method, doing the loops outside, at the point where you're currently calling the methods. Either way, you _have to_ do some looping somewhere to process the arrays.

Comment: Got it!!!!! Now I got it working. Thanks sooooooo much. You rock!!! I wish I was half as smart as you. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2805621 oh, it was nothing :) my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at this method...

```
public static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(double cel){ //These parameters.. nono
    double fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = (9.0/5)*(cel+32); //Use all doubles (9.0/5.0)*(cel+32.0);
    return fahrenheit;
    // Method CelsiusToFahrenheit end <-- this makes no sense, read method name
}
```

You take in an `array` of cel instead of just cel. Change the paramaters to `double cel`. The same applies for your other method.

Comment: Alright. So I removed the [] from the parameters. Now I get errors at // passes fahren to method                                       
  FahrenheitToCelsius(fahren);
  
  // passes cel to method
  CelsiusToFahrenheit(cel);      and what it says for them is "The method CelsiusToFahrenheit(double) in the type CelciusFahrenheit is not applicable for the arguments (double[])"

Comment: How is this different from OP's problem? You're still trying to add a n array to an integer

Comment: Read the comments. If you couldn't piece one and two together then I don't really know why you are on here. I've removed the two []s just for your convenience. Next time try to really read the answer before posting some retarded reply.